# VBA merge and unmerge according to if statement

Tags: vba, excel, merge

**Example Image**
[image]

I am having an issue with merging data in excel using VBA.

Basically, I would like every cell row to be the same size and when a cell matches with a specific name, I want certain cells (specific 2 sets of rows preceding the name) to merge and center while others just merge across but that way some cells in the column have one number while others have a percentage and fraction as seen in this picture example above.

I'm wondering if offset could be useful here as well?

Here is some pseudo ish code to give you an idea: basically, if a cell in the A range matches a color (or whatever I put), then we want to merge and center two rows of cells and the 3 columns. Else if the cell in the A range matches a name (or whatever I put), then leave the cells separate but merge across maybe.

```
sub example1()

if (cell in A range) = "red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue",
then offset ( , 1) and merge&center 
else if (cell in A range) = "sarah", "mark", "bob", "steve", "Brittany",
then offset (, 1) and leavealone or merge just across

end if

end sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You'll need to provide a more specific problem and some code if you really want to get help from this site.

Comment: okay I added a picture doc of the spreadsheet and changed my question a bit. For security reasons, I had to make it a pretty bland example (obviously can't use my real data), but I think this gives a good idea of what I am trying to do. Any help is appreciated. I'm fairly new to vba, so bear with me

Comment: does the data in column start as 1 name per row? and is your lookup table already merged?

Comment: the data in column A is 1 name per 2 rows. So, that column is full of static data and can start already merged whereas column B will merge or remain split depending on what is next to it in column A.

Comment: I need more explanation about names... 1. Did you know all names? it's constants or dynamically list ? 2. What about cell with name, if this name not match to your condition (it's new name)? Maybe better will be to merge all cells with any name, excluding only those with should be left alone? 3. for 'Sarah' and 'Mark' it's one cell with 2 lines or it's two cells? 4. Why 'Yellow' is 18?

Answer (score 0):

Like Scott Holtzman said more specific question and any example will be great to better understanding... However base on what we have:

> I'm thinking I need to first merge and center every 2 cells, then need an if statement saying if it highlights a cell with " " whatever name that needs to be split, unmerge the cells, else leave them merged and cantered.

Doing something and the next undoing this in the same action is probably not good idea... Better is if you check conditions before and then you perform only one specific action.

I assume that you use some kind of loop ? So, do you can check your 'if/else' condition first and then perform merge or split ?

*Really, example will be very helpful here.*

> I'm wondering if offset could be useful here as well?

I can't imagine for what? If I understand your question, you need just `if / else if / else' condition in your VBA.

Comment: okay I added a picture doc of the spreadsheet and changed my question a bit. For security reasons, I had to make it a pretty bland example (obviously can't use my real data), but I think this gives a good idea of what I am trying to do. Any help is appreciated. I'm fairly new to vba, so bear with me.